# Compare and map values in two table with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables:

`df1`:

| Branch | Dept | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 10000 |
| A | 2 | 10001 |
| A | 3 | 10003 |
| B | 1 | 20000 |
| B | 2 | 20001 |
| ... | ... | ... |

`df2`:

| Branch | Dept | Code | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 |  | ... |
| B | 2 |  | ... |
| A | 3 |  | ... |
| B | 1 |  | ... |
| A | 2 |  | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to map the Code column in df1 to the Code column in df2. The condition is in each combination of Branch and Dept will have a code, and sometimes, one Code can have multiple Branch-Dept.

I have tried to convert to dictionary for comparison:

```
foo = {}
for i in df1["Code"].unique():
    foo[i] = [{df1["Branch"][j]: df1["Dept"][j]} for j in mapping_table[df1["Code"] == i].index]
    
bar = dict(zip(df2["Branch"], df2["Dept"]))
```

My target table (df2) have around 10000 rows, if possible, is there any way to get all values faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `map`:

```
cols = ['Branch','Dept']
df2['Code'] = df2.set_index(cols).index.map(df1.set_index(cols)['Code'])
```

or you could `merge`:

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, on=cols)
```

Output:

```
  Branch  Dept   Code
0      A     1  10000
1      B     2  20001
2      A     3  10003
3      B     1  20000
4      A     2  10001
```

Comment: I have tried the map method and I have an error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects". I have checked duplicated columns on both tables and used reset_index also but still have that error.

Comment: @AndrewHoang That's weird; can the same Branch-Dept pair have multiple codes?

Comment: Nope, the Branch-Dept pair is unique and 1 code can be used for multiple pairs.

Comment: @AndrewHoang `df2.merge(df1, on=cols, how='left')` matches all branch-dept pairs in `df2` with existing pairs in `df1`. If you're getting NaN values, then it means for some pairs, the corresponding code doesn't exist in `df1`.

Comment: I want to ask if it is possible that I can merge some rows based on their value. For example, if Branch == 'A' then merge on 2 columns (on='cols' have 2 columns), else merge on 3 columns (on='cols' have 3 columns).